# Disable Multithreading in Unittest

Tags: python, multithreading, unit-testing

I'm trying to "unit test" some lab exercices. Every test must me executed one at a time to set a specific "state" for the next test. The problem is it seems that Unittest is using some multithreading. How can I disable this behaviour?

```
def test_question2(self):
    elasticsearch = SOUP.find("question2").text
    subprocess.Popen(elasticsearch)
    print("here2")
    time.sleep(15)
    ping = requests.get("http://localhost:9200")
    self.assertEqual(ping.status_code, 200)


def test_quest6(self):
    kill_process("Elasticsearch")
    elasticsearch = SOUP.find("question6").text
    print("here6")
    subprocess.Popen(elasticsearch)
    ping = requests.get("http://localhost:9200")
    json_ping = ping.json()
    node_name = json_ping["name"]
    self.assertEqual(node_name, "node_name")
```

I can see that the print are mixed, this is why I think Unit test is using multithreading.

Comment: What brought you to that conclusion? Can you provide an example of the issues you are facing with your unit tests? What is the exact problem that you are seeing in your tests that is giving you unexpected results. A code example would be needed here.

Comment: @idjaw I use sleep in two of my test, and I can see that they are executed in the same time.

Comment: What unit test framework are you using? Because the standard `unittest` I don't believe makes use of threading by default. Did you look at the unittest code itself to see if it in fact explicitly using multithreading?

Comment: @idjaw I'm using `import unittest`in python3 and I edited the question to add some samples

Comment: unittest doesn't multithread tests.  Can you show the output you are seeing?  You say the prints are interleaved, but you only have two print lines in the code.